# I have TRRS earphones. PC cannot record audio even with a splitter

Tags: windows

I realized that my earphones work with my laptop but not my Windows 10 PC because PC uses two slots (speaker and mic). I bought a splitter to split my 3.5mm jack into two (headphone and mic). I can hear with my earphones and the mic is now recognized but it's not recording anything. When I test it under sound settings the bar doesn't move at all.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on a windows 10 laptop. in my case the problem was that one of the pins of the Female Jack Port was not connecting to the Male Jack Port. make sure the following has been done:

1. sound driver installed correctly.
2. the volume is not mute or too low
3. Headphones/earphones can work well on other devices.

This is what I have done: disassemble the back cover of the laptop, then press the pin of the female jack port using a needle gently and slowly.

Disclaimer: I am not responsible for what you do. I'm just trying to answer the question.

Sorry, my English is bad.

Regards